# Retrieving all database objects and its related objects Django

Tags: django

I am currently learning Django, and I am finding it a bit difficult wrapping my head around the `ManyToMany` fields. I am using an intermediate model to manage my relationships.

I have three models; `Ticket`, `User`, and `TicketUserRelation`.
I want to be able to query the ticket model, and retrieve both its corresponding user objects and the ticket object. How would I go about doing this?

In Laravel I would do something along the lines of

```
Ticket::where('id', '1')->with('contributors')
```

But I can't really figure out how to do this in Django

The models:

```
class User(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

class Ticket(models.Model):
    contributors = models.ManyToManyField(User, through=TicketUserRelation, related_name='tickets')

    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    created_at = models.DateField()

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

class TicketUserRelation(models.Model):
    id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True, db_column='relation_id')
    ticket = models.ForeignKey(Ticket, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

EDIT: I am using an intermediate model so that I can easily add things like join date later.

Comment: `Ticket.objects.filter(id=1).prefetch_related('contributors')`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out myself, using `prefetch_related`. I was having trouble understanding how `prefetch_related` works. For those that are confused too, from my understanding it works like this:

```
Ticket.objects.all().prefetch_related('contributors')
```

This returns a queryset, something along the lines of this

```
<QuerySet [<Ticket: Testing ticket one>, <Ticket: Testing ticket two>, <Ticket: Testing ticket three'>, <Ticket: Testing ticket four>]>
```

When you then access the elements in the queryset, you can then call `.contributors` on the object, like so:

```
# Get the queryset
tickets_with_contribs = Ticket.objects.all().prefetch_related('contributors')

# Print the contributors of the first ticket returned
print(tickets_with_contribs[0].contributors)

# Print the contributors of each ticket
for ticket in tickets_with_contribs:
    print(ticket.contributors)
```

Looking back at it this should have been pretty self explanatory, but oh well.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need the `TicketUserRelation` model when using Django ORM. You could simply use a `ForeignKey` in the `Ticket` model, or use the `ManyToManyField` already defined, if one ticket can be assigned to multiple users.

```py
class Ticket(models.Model):

    # For one user, use ForeignKey
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='tickets')
    # For multiple users, use ManyToManyField
    contributors = models.ManyToManyField(User, related_name='tickets')

    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    created_at = models.DateField()

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

You can then get all tickets for a user `u` with:

```
u.tickets.all()
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I want to use an intermediate model so that I can add  join date and more info later, just wanted to get the basics working first. I'll update my post to be more clear on this.